# Nodejs extending Sequelize model

Tags: node.js, class, oop, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize in a project. There are some models there, such as the following:

```
class Agents extends CommonModel {

  static init(sequelize) {
    return super.init({
      ...super.baseFields,
      userId: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        references: User
      },
      ...
    }, {
        sequelize,
        timestamps: true,
        paranoid: true
      })
  }
```

Also in CommonModel:

```
class CommonModel extends Model {

  static baseFields = {
    createdBy: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'Users',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    ...
  }
  
}
```

Now, here is the question, what is the `sequelize` parameter in init function? (I don't call it directly). When is init going to being called? (there is no constructor though)
Is this a special design pattern?

Answer (score 1):

1. I think keyword `super` refers to parent class and constructs it with `super.init()` arguments.
2. you did call `sequelize` in `Agent` model so parameter is needed right? and maybe class `model` has `sequelize` variable

Comment: I just don't understand about the parameter. There is no `sequelize` parameter defined in any place. (if it was `implements` instead of `extend` that was ok because that is `strategy` design pattern. But here, I'm confused.

Comment: @Vahid  Najafi Maybe its a just a declaration. So that when agent class instance is called it could take sequelize class as an constructor. I am actually confused also